# multiple linedataset label didn't show MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to show the label of my LineDataSet, but it didn't show on my android chart. It should be 4 labels at the bottom, with 4 different colors and names. I simply the code so I can post it here

Here is my code :

```
        val chartLineDataSet = LineDataSet(arrayData, "Phasa A")
        chartLineDataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
        chartLineDataSet.color = Color.RED
        chartLineDataSet.circleRadius = 5f
        chartLineDataSet.lineWidth = 2f
        chartLineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.RED)
        chartLineDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.RED
        chartLineDataSet.valueTextSize = 10F
        chartLineDataSet.setDrawValues(false)
        chartLineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false)
        chartLineDataSet.valueFormatter = MyValueFormatter()

        val lineDatas: MutableList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList()
        lineDatas.add(chartLineDataSet)

        binding.lineChart.let {

            it.description.isEnabled = false
            it.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            it.data = LineData(lineDatas)
            it.animateXY(100, 500)

            it.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)

            it.axisLeft.textColor = Color.BLACK
            it.axisRight.textColor = Color.BLACK
            it.xAxis.textColor = Color.BLACK
            it.legend.textColor = Color.BLACK

            it.axisRight.isEnabled = false
            it.axisLeft.isEnabled = true

            it.isClickable = false

            it.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(7F)
        }
```

and the result for the code above

[image: chart]

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to set enabled / true the `binding.chart.legend`. Finally, the labels are already shown.